# How to get Netgear WNA 3100 work with Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.04, netgear

I am wondering about how to get my WNA 3100 wireless adapter to work with my Ubuntu 17.04 desktop. When plugged in, my computer is not showing any signs that it recognized the adapter. I know there are similar questions, but none of them seemed to help me. I have no idea where/how to start, and it would be very much appreciated if someone could help. Thank you!

Comment: Don't waste your time (and others').

Comment: Please see: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264020&highlight=wna3100